# Images size and mouse hover

Tags: css

in this page
http://demos.roxiwd.com/index.php/ar/kgar

How to show images normal like the next row
and how to show the words once the mouse hover any point on image not the word area.

Comment: You'll need to provide what you've done so far, at least provide your `HTML` structure.

Comment: Please, isolate the current CSS and HTML in the Codepen or similar  website.

Answer (score 0):

```
img:hover .words {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you have a dynamic column width and a fixed height on your image containers (with `background-size` set to `100% 100%`). This results in deformed images. You say you want to change that on hover. To do so, you first need to reset the height of this container:

```
.uc_animated_border_banner:hover .uc_animated_border_bg {height: auto!important;}
```

Next you should use the [padding trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css#10441480) to set the (now dynamic) height equal to the aspect ratio. The aspect ratio of the image is 450px/350px = 1.29. This equals to 129% padding-bottom. Correct this for the line-height of the element that actually takes up verticale space in the box (the h2, with a height of 30px) and you end up with `129% - 30px` for the padding-bottom. Split this for equal padding top and bottom, and you end up with `64.5% - 15px` padding on both top and bottom of the h2 element. This results in a box with an exact aspect ratio of 1.29 (as long as the h2 fits on a single line).

```
.uc_animated_border_banner:hover .uc_animated_border_banner .uc_content_box h2 {
  padding-top: calc(64.5% - 15px)!important;
  padding-bottom: calc(64.5% - 15px)!important;
}
```

TIP: Use `position: absolute` on the h2 for a solution without the 15px/30px and single-line constraint.

---

Although this works I would chose for a more simple solution. Find the inline CSS statement at line 214:

```
.uc_animated_border_bg {background-size: 100% 100%!important;}
```

... and replace it with:

```
.uc_animated_border_bg {background-size: cover!important;}
```

I think the result looks better and the solution is much simpler. This alternative solution works for any image (irrespective of their aspect ratio). The only down-side is that an unknown amount of the image is invisible/cut off.

Comment: .uc_content_box h2 {
 color: transparent !important;
 padding-top: calc(64.5% - 15px) !important;
 padding-bottom: calc(64.5% - 15px) !important;
}

Comment: .uc_animated_border_banner .uc_animated_border_bg {
 height: auto !important;
}